# Upgrade failed - from SP 2013 RTM to SP 2013 SP1 with APRIL 2017 CU

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, upgrade, service-pack

while upgrading the  SP 2013 RTM to SP1  with April 2o17 CU,and after running the command       psconfig.exe -cmd upgrade -inplace b2b -force on the command prompt
am getting the below error in the error.log file:
having a custom timer job feature is beamea orphaned/unwanted  element.
 how can i remove this feature/soln from this farm,so that my farm is upgraded successfully.

> Timestamp                 Process                                     TID     Area                            Category                        EventID Level       Message     Correlation
>   06/28/2017 18:57:44.05  PSCONFIG (0x1E9C)   0x2320  SharePoint Foundation Upgrade   SPUpgradeSession    ajxmm   INFO    SPContentDatabase Name=SharePoint_AdminContent_f8c70f4f-4086-4ab... 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
>   06/28/2017 18:57:44.05  PSCONFIG (0x1E9C)   0x2320  SharePoint Foundation Upgrade   SPUpgradeSession    ajxmm   WARNING Exception occured when querying feature with id [57996672-7e89-4082-b77e-66b6020ac924], skipping. Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException: Failed to find the XML file at location '15\Template\Features\JobReminders_TimerJob_Timer_JobRemindersFeature\feature.xml'     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPXmlDocCache.GetGlobalXmlDocument(String pathTemplateRelativeXml, SPFeatureDefinition featdef, Int32 compatibilityLevel)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPFarmFeatureDefinitionContext.LoadFileAsXmlDocument(SPFeatureDefinition featdef, String feature RelativePath)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPFeatureDefinition.get_Scope()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPUpgradeSession.PopulateFeaturesTable(StringBuilder sqlstr)  00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000

[image: UPGRADE-FAILED]

[image: upgrade-failed-22]

Would like to  add one more info. on this.  the site collec in which i am runing these operations was a content-db-restore from another SP 2013 farm with same config-db version.
So does it mean that, this orphaned timer job info./feature was not removed from  that farm? since its a timer job and  deployed on a web appln scope, its  still available in the farm.

[image: faulty-feature1]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The upgrade error indicates you have a custom Full Trust Solution in place that appears to be missing (from the description, it is a timer job). This won't necessarily cause the upgrade to fail overall, but likely something you should resolve, either by forcing the feature removal if the FTC is no longer deployed; [Feature Admin](https://github.com/achimismaili/featureadmin) is a popular tool for this, or redeploying the FTC to the farm so the definition for it is in place.

Comment: its a good info, didnt hear about this FeatureAdmin!  Instead Heard about SharePoint manager only.

Comment: i got to see the faulty feature through feature admin , but there is  no button to delete that feature! i have updated my question with featureadmin screen shot. other tab shows remove /deactivate, but for the farm scoped feature , there is no way to remove those( it seems ).

Comment: featureadmin is a wonderful tool, i was able to find  out the faulty features and delete those using powershell cmdlets. Thanks again Trevor! :-) Finally  my upgrade was  successfull !

Answer (score 1):

[You ran a PSConfig-Command that is incomplete](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/stefan_gossner/2015/08/20/why-i-prefer-psconfigui-exe-over-psconfig-exe/). Try to run the following:

PSConfig.exe -cmd upgrade -inplace b2b -wait -cmd applicationcontent -install -cmd installfeatures -cmd secureresources -cmd services -install

If the above command doesn't work in the first run, simply try to run it twice. If this also doesn't work, try to run "SharePoint Products Configuration Wizard" from Windows Start-Menu.

There is a good chance to get your Farm up-to-date. In the long run you should follow Trevor's recommendation and check the orphaned solution.